# Mocha framework to test outbound client request

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

My usecase:

Implement an automation test to capture onbound client request after opening a page in browser. For example, open http://foo.com that later makes beacon call to http://bar.com with few parameters.

Question:
How do I test whether foo.com has initiated a call to bar.com? Can mocha do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I found a way to capture all requests being made by a page using phantomjs, it has a node module called phantom (https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) that can open a page and a listener would give all resources being requested.

Sample javascript code,

```js
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    
    page.open("http://ramcountry.yahoo.com", function (status) {
      console.log("opened site? ", status);
    });
    
    page.set('onResourceRequested', function(requestData, networkRequest) {
      console.log("requested: ", requestData.url);
    });
    
    page.set('onResourceReceived', function(requestData, networkRequest) {
      console.log("received: ", requestData.url);
    });
    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mocha (by design) doesn't provide this kind of thing, but can integrate with other tools (as you noted in your other answer) to provide test benefits. However your answer didn't display any testing, so I'm going to drop a few frameworks in here specifically designed for testing:

- http://nightwatchjs.org/
- http://www.cypress.io/
- http://webdriver.io/